# I runed rosrun gazebo_ros debug and I get this at end. signal SIGFPE?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ INFO] [1400250293.615927480]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1400250293.617035719]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.10.234
[New Thread 0xa9df8b40 (LWP 10393)]

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0xb1e28fd2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165691/i-runed-rosrun-gazebo_ros-debug-and-i-get-this-at-end.-signal-sigfpe??/) by [Moussa](https://answers.ros.org/users/17961/moussa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a floating point error; it means that a program tried to do an illegal floating-point operation, such as dividing by zero or infinity.

Since the library in question is libdrm_radeon, which is part of the graphics driver, I suspect this is a either a rendering bug or a bug in your graphics drivers.

You may want to try upgrading your graphics drivers to the official ATI drivers.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0